# bigrams instead of single words in termdocument matrix using R and Rweka

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I've found a way to use use bigrams instead of single tokens in a term-document matrix. The solution has been posed on stackoverflow here:  [findAssocs for multiple terms in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836022/findassocs-for-multiple-terms-in-r)

The idea goes something like this:

```
library(tm)
library(RWeka)
data(crude)

#Tokenizer for n-grams and passed on to the term-document matrix constructor
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))
txtTdmBi <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
```

However the final line gives me the error:

```
Error in rep(seq_along(x), sapply(tflist, length)) : 
  invalid 'times' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

If I remove the tokenizer from the last line it creates a regular tdm, so I guess the problem is somewhere in the BigramTokenizer function although this is the same example that the Weka site gives here: http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html#Bigrams.

Comment: It works fine for me; I can't reproduce your error message. You might try updating your packages and R to make sure you're using the latest version of everything.

Comment: Thanks again for your advice. I still get the error message after checking my version of R and update.packages. I wonder if this is a os problem as I often run into Java problems on OS X so maybe its effecting weka? Will try on my windows machine. I'll give this a try too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898521/finding-2-3-word-phrases-using-r-tm-package

Comment: Yes, the next step is making sure your Java installation is all in order (and this can be quite a frustrating task!). I don't use OSX, maybe it's not so bad, but Windows doesn't make it easy...

Comment: I had a look at my Java installation. I couldn't see anything out of the ordinary. Now I don't receive the error message but my Mac hangs when I try to run the code. Historically I have had problems with OS X and various bits of kit built in Java. The code snippet does however work perfectly on my Windows box.

Comment: Seeing the same problem.  Turned debug on and narrowed down this line.  Works fine with default scan_tokenizer but returns NULLs even with NGramTokenizer

    `parallel::mclapply(corpus, FUN=termFreq, control = list(tokenize = scan_tokenizer))`

Answer (score 31):

Inspired by Anthony's comment, I found out that you can specify the number of threads that the `parallel` library uses by default (specify it before you call the `NgramTokenizer`):

```
# Sets the default number of threads to use
options(mc.cores=1)
```

Since the `NGramTokenizer` seems to hang on the `parallel::mclapply` call, changing the number of threads seems to work around it.

Comment: Didn't experience the problem but in Shinyapps.io. This solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Seems there are problems using **RWeka** with **parallel** package. I found workaround solution [here.](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/RWeka-and-multicore-package-td4678473.html#a4678948)

> The most important point is not loading the RWeka package and use the namespace in a encapsulated  function.

So your tokenizer should look like

```
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) {RWeka::NGramTokenizer(x, RWeka::Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2))}
```

Comment: Is there any alternative to NGramTokenizer ? In my computer RWeka is not working due to some R / Java version issues.