# How to implement a backup tokenizer switch in RWeka?

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, rweka

I am using R-tm-Rweka packages to do some text mining. Instead of building a tf-tdm on single words, which is not enough for my purposes, i have to extract ngrams. I used [@Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615181/finding-ngrams-in-r-and-comparing-ngrams-across-corpora?rq=1) function `TrigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 3))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(a, control = list(tokenize = TrigramTokenizer))`

to extract trigrams. The output has an apparent error, see below. It picks up 4-, 3- and 2-word phrases. Ideally, it should have ONLY picked up the 4-word noun phrase and dropped the (3- and 2-word)rest. How do I force this solution, like Python NLTK has a backup tokenizer option?

abstract strategy             `->this is incorrect`>
  abstract strategy board        `->incorrect`
  abstract strategy board game   `-> this should be the correct output`

accenture executive
  accenture executive simple
  accenture executive simple comment

Many thanks.

Comment: So, to summarize, you want to do 2-gram and 3-gram, right?

Comment: Say: try a 4-gram first, then try a 3-word window then a 2-word window, failing a single word. But report only the largest relevant item (don't repeat 4-, 3-,2-word phrases)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were very close with the attempt that you made. Except that you have to understand that what you were telling `Weka` to do was to capture 2-gram and 3-gram tokens; that's just how `Weka_control` was specified.

Instead I'd recommend to use the different token sizes in different tokenizers and select or merge the results according to your preference or decision rule.

I think it would be worth checking out this [great tutorial](http://hack-r.com/n-gram-wordclouds-in-r/) on n-gram wordclouds.

A solid code snippet for n-gram text mining is:

```
# QuadgramTokenizer ####
QuadgramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 4, max = 4)
```

for 4-grams,

```
# TrigramTokenizer ####
TrigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 3, max = 3)
```

For 3-grams, and of course

```
# BigramTokenizer ####
BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max = 2)
```

for 2-grams.

You might be able to avoid your earlier problem by running the different gram sizes separately like this instead of setting `Weka_control` to a range.

You can apply the tokenizer like this:

```
tdm.ng <- TermDocumentMatrix(ds5.1g, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
dtm.ng <- DocumentTermMatrix(ds5.1g, control = list(tokenize = BigramTokenizer))
```

If you still have problems please just provide a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example and I'll follow up.

Comment: Thanks Hack-R. I ran this snippet. The problem has moved elsewhere, instead of getting the term document matrix to reflect 4-,-3,-2 gram phrases, i am still getting single words. Example: 'deutsche' is valid but 'deutche bank' (which I want recognised as a valid bigram) is not recognised. where is the issue in my understanding?

Comment: @Pradeep I see. In order for me to be able to help I need a reproducible example, so that I can see the problem on my computer and try somethings to see what fixes it. Can you use a built-in or public data set and then paste the full code to reproduce this problem?

Comment: i will post a reproducible data set. Meanwhile, I checked out [@Ben](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836022/findassocs-for-multiple-terms-in-r). I think i can define my problem more precisely: Instead of NGram route, I just want term frequencies of identified/specified (4-, 3-, 2-words); the vectors being stored as columns in a term document matrix. Like <col 1>Deloitte Haskin Sells <col2>Price Waterhouse <col3>Lexis Nexis and so on.

Comment: both `tm` and `Weka:: NGramTokenizer` are terrible (ram consumption and implementation). Check `text2vec` as much more efficient alternative.

Comment: @Hack-R : Reverting to the main question: as suggested above, I create a list of (bigrams, trigrams and 4-grams). Problem is to superset this list such that (a) discard a bigram if it exists in the trigram, AND  (b) add the bigram count to the trigram count. In above 4-gram example, here are the counts: 
abstract strategy  8
abstract strategy board  3
abstract strategy board game 2. 
I should be able to chain the above as "abstract strategy board game" (largest n-gram, because items 1 & 2 are already included) with count 8+3+2=13. Any help will be useful.