# R and tm package: create a term-document matrix with a dictionary of one or two words?

Tags: r, tm, n-gram, term-document-matrix, rweka

**Purpose:**  I want to create a *term-document matrix* using a *dictionary* which has compound words, or *bigrams*, as some of the *keywords*.

**Web Search:**  Being new to text-mining and the `tm` package in `R`, I went to the web to figure out how to do this.  Below are some relevant links that I found:

- [FAQS on the tm-package website](http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html#Bigrams)
- [finding 2 & 3 word phrases using r tm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898521/finding-2-3-word-phrases-using-r-tm-package)
- [counter ngram with tm package in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764187/counter-ngram-with-tm-package-in-r)
- [findassocs for multiple terms in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836022/findassocs-for-multiple-terms-in-r)

**Background:**  Of these, I preferred the solution that uses `NGramTokenizer` in the `RWeka` package in `R`, **but I ran into a problem**.  In the example code below, I create three documents and place them in a *corpus*.  Note that `Docs 1` and `2` each contain two words.  `Doc 3` only contains one word.  My dictionary keywords are two bigrams and a unigram.

**Problem:** The `NGramTokenizer` solution in the above links does not correctly count the unigram keyword in the `Doc 3`.

```
library(tm)
library(RWeka)

my.docs = c('jedi master', 'jedi grandmaster', 'jedi')
my.corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(my.docs))
my.dict = c('jedi master', 'jedi grandmaster', 'jedi')

BigramTokenizer <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 2))

inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(my.corpus, control=list(tokenize=BigramTokenizer,
                                                  dictionary=my.dict)))

# <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 3, terms: 3)>>
# ...
# Docs  jedi  jedi grandmaster  jedi master
#    1     1                 0            1
#    2     1                 1            0
#    3     0                 0            0
```

I was expecting the row for `Doc 3` to give `1` for `jedi` and `0` for the other two.  Is there something I am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and found that token counting functions from the TM package rely on an option called **wordLengths**, which is a vector of two numbers -- the minimum and the maximum length of tokens to keep track of. By default, TM uses a minimum word length of 3 characters (`wordLengths = c(3, Inf)`). You can override this option by adding it to the **control** list in a call to **DocumentTermMatrix** like this:

```
DocumentTermMatrix(my.corpus,
                   control=list(
                       tokenize=newBigramTokenizer,
                       wordLengths = c(1, Inf)))
```

However, your 'jedi' word is more than 3 characters long. Although, you probably tweaked the option's value earlier while trying to figure out how to count ngrams, so still try this. Also, look at the **bounds** option, which tells TM to discard words less or more frequent than specified values.

Comment: Thnx for pointer to `wordlengths` in the control. I thought something like this was going on when I couldn't find the word "tv" but could when I replaced it with "television" throughout my data.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that `NGramTokenizer` returns `character(0)` when a one-word string is submitted as input and `NGramTokenizer` is asked to return unigrams and bigrams.

```
NGramTokenizer('jedi',  Weka_control(min = 1, max = 2))
# character(0)
```

I am not sure why this is the output, but I believe this behavior is the reason why the keyword `jedi` was not counted in `Doc 3`.  However, a simple `if-then-else` solution appears to work for my situation: both for the sample set and my actual data set.

```
library(tm)
library(RWeka)    

my.docs = c('jedi master', 'jedi grandmaster', 'jedi')
my.corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(my.docs))
my.dict = c('jedi master', 'jedi grandmaster', 'jedi')

newBigramTokenizer = function(x) {
  tokenizer1 = NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 1, max = 2))
  if (length(tokenizer1) != 0L) { return(tokenizer1)
  } else return(WordTokenizer(x))
} # WordTokenizer is an another tokenizer in the RWeka package.

inspect(DocumentTermMatrix(my.corpus, control=list(tokenize=newBigramTokenizer,
                                                 dictionary=my.dict)))

# <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 3, terms: 3)>>
# ...
# Docs jedi jedi grandmaster jedi master
#   1    1                0           1
#   2    1                1           0
#   3    1                0           0
```

Please let me know if anyone finds a "gotcha" that I am not considering in the code above.  I would also appreciate any insight into why `NGramTokenizer` returns `character(0)` in my observation above.