# Group similar text with their references R

Tags: r, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, text-mining, topic-modeling

I am trying to cluster groups of ideas, each one as a reference.
Each rows contain an idea, the csv looks like this:

```
library(tm)
setwd("/Users/Bif/Documents")
#read the data
data<-read.csv("ideas.csv", header=T, sep=";")
> data
 Reference                                                   idea
1 FI-000786          AIRE DE DETENTE LES BEAUX JOURS ARRIVENT etc…
2 FI-000754   Tiroirs de rangement des véhicules  les tiroirs etc…
3 FI-000740   EVITER LES PI Vaines sur sur les dossiers MOAR etc..
4 FI-000717    Glossaire de sigleset trigrammes ucf beaucoup  etc…
5 FI-000705        Transport de l'escabeau Bruit et accès de  etc…
6 FI-000669  economie de papier  C.Q.P (avis de passage avec  etc…
7 FI-000653          UTILISATION D 'UNE CAMERA D'INSPECTION  etc..
8 FI-000649  faciliter les déclarations de SD par les agents  etc…
9 FI-000639 Récup Embase téléreport sur coffret Des coffrets  etc…
```

I'm quite new with R. I've been trying with the text-mining tm-package and I can analyze the terms frequencies of the second column via a DoumentTermMatrix, the problem is with this process I'm only able to analyse it as if it was a plain text, not as different groups of text that I could compare afterwards and tell which references are similar to each others.

I've seen there is this [qpad package topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677292/r-create-a-term-frequency-matrix-using-2-columns-from-a-csv-file-in-r) which might get close to what I am looking for (even though I can't make it to load the package, don't know why yet..) but I can't figure out how I would cluster each references (dates in the link example)  together anyway.

I've been searching quite a lot in on the web, I feel stuck now...

Thank you a lot.

Comment: You could paste all idea's per reference together, making a longer text and use that in the package tm?

Comment: You should try to factor the column.
See
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251326/convert-data-frame-column-format-from-character-to-factor 
for details

Comment: @WannesRosiers Well if I put it all together in one text I don't think I will be able to distinct the reference in the end (It's kinda what I did in the first place with tm). Plus it would be more difficult to compare the idea content I think.

Comment: @JoeChakra I'm not sure I understood how it works I'll try to dig it more.. 

The two main problems I have are, first I'm struggling to do a comparison of similarities between those ideas. - Second , even if I figure it out I think the text minig operation will prevent me from keeping the link reference/idea.

Comment: You may want to look at topic modeling (like the topicmodel package or LDA package).  Those capabilities can cluster your text into topics.

Comment: @lawyeR it's not exactly what I'm looking for since I  don't want to find topics but simply cluster the most similar ideas (portion of text). But I find it is not not that simple in the end... it's kind of a k-mean except k-mean is unfortunately only for numerics.

I have found ways to get the frequencies of words (with tm-package) but then I struggle to correlate this info to tell which portion of text is close to another and forms a group.And all of this by keeping the reference in mind.

Comment: @lawyeR If I can find the topics out of it, do you think it's possible to associate the references to each topic afterwards? I doubt it is feasable..

Answer (score 0):

Create a DocumentTermMatrix with tm, then turn that DocumentTermMatrix into a DataFrame with `as.data.frame(as.matrix(mydtm))`, then cbind()  the reference column back to the new data frame. Alternatively cbind the converted DoctermMatrix (->DataFrame) back to your original data frame for further processing.

Comment: I found something wrong with my DocumentTermMatrix I only have 34 Terms in it, which is completely wrong:
`
    > corp<-Corpus(DataframeSource(data))
    > dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
    > dim(dtm)
    [1] 133  34 `